# Resolving SignalR dependencies in a fashion similar to PerRequestLifetimeManager

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, signalr, unity-container

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4.5 Web API application that also uses SignalR in certain situations. This means that the underlying business logic can be called by Web Api Controllers and from SignalR hubs.

Dependencies are injected using Unity and I have designed the application to reuse repositories and ApplicationDbContext using PerRequestLifetimeManager. As many repositories access the database this is supposed to limit the amount of database connections that are opened. At the end of the request in the controller I call SaveChanges() and the changes that are effected by the complete request are stored in the database.

This behavior works when I use Web Api, but I run into some trouble when SignalR is used: I have created a hybrid LifetimeManager that behaves as a PerRequestLifetimeManager when a Http Request exists and as a TransientLifetimeManager when none does (it's a SignalR request then). The trouble is that the various repositories created during the SignalR call then all get their own ApplicationDbContext instance and SaveChanges() is never called on those.

So, I need a lifetime manager that works like PerRequestLifetimeManager but for SignalR. Can anybody help me out? Or am I on the wrong track here and should each repository always get its own instance of ApplicationDbContext and call SaveChanges() itself when changes can be persisted? I haven't done this, because I though I'd have too many database connections and I'd like to have something like one transaction for the whole request.